# JavaScript waiting until an image is fully loaded before continuing script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been looking around a lot of JavaScript answers but I haven't found one that really answers my problem yet. What I'm trying to do is load an image, grab the pixel data, perform an analysis, and then load another image to repeat the process.

My problem is that I can't preload all of the images because this script has to be able to work on large amounts of images and preloading could be too resource heavy. So I'm stuck trying to load a new image each time through a loop, but I'm stuck with a race condition between the image loading and the script drawing it to the canvas's context. At least I'm pretty sure that's what is happening because the script will work fine with the images precached (for example if I refresh after loading the page previously).

As you'll see there are several lines of code commented out because I'm incredibly new to JavaScript and they weren't working the way I thought they would, but I didn't want to forget about them if I needed the functionality later.

This is the snippet of code that I believe is giving rise to the problem:

EDIT: So I got my function to work after following a suggestion

```
 function myFunction(imageURLarray) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('imagecanvas');
  console.log("Canvas Grabbed");

  if (!canvas || !canvas.getContext) {
    return;
  }

  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  if (!context || !context.putImageData) {
    return;
  }

  window.loadedImageCount = 0;
  loadImages(context, canvas.width, canvas.height, imageURLarray, 0);
}

function loadImages(context, width, height, imageURLarray, currentIndex) {
  if (imageURLarray.length == 0 || imageURLarray.length == currentIndex) {
    return false;
  }
  if (typeof currentIndex == 'undefined') {
    currentIndex = 0;
  }

  var currentimage = new Image();
  currentimage.src = imageURLarray[currentIndex];

  var tempindex = currentIndex;
  currentimage.onload = function(e) {

    // Function code here

    window.loadedImageCount++;

    if (loadedImageCount == imageURLarray.length) {

      // Function that happens after all images are loaded here
    }
  }
  currentIndex++;
  loadImages(context, width, height, imageURLarray, currentIndex);
  return;
}
```

Comment: This question still gets views 4 years later so I thought I mention that if you have a lot of images you may want to call the recursive `loadImages` with `setTimeout(..., 0)` so that the call stack doesn't overflow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
currentimage.onload = function(e){
    // code, run after image load
}
```

If it is necessary to wait for the image to load, the following code will load the next image (currentIndex is your "img" variable):

```
var loadImages = function(imageURLarray, currentIndex){
    if (imageURLarray.length == 0 || imageURLarray.length == currentIndex) return false;
    if (typeof currentIndex == 'undefined'){
       currentIndex = 0;
    }
    // your top code
    currentimage.onload = function(e){
        // code, run after image load
        loadImages(imageURLArray, currentIndex++);
    }
}
```

Instead of a "for" loop, use for example this function:

```
loadImages(imageURLarray);
```

Comment: I was looking at this but my understanding is that the rest of the script will continue to run until the image loads and that function is triggered, and so I'll have the same race condition.

Comment: @Braains, If properly implemented, then no. If you have another code, show it

Comment: onload won't wait  to load next images

Comment: Give me a few minutes here to implement this and see if it works! But I'm inclined to agree with @roasted

Comment: "@Braains, What I see now: you only need all the code that begin with console.log('Image drawn') insert in callback.

Comment: @maximkou can you give me an example of what you mean? I don't see how a callback stops JavaScript from running without the image being fully loaded.

Comment: That could work! Let me implement it, I'll be back with results in a few.

Comment: @Braains but this is basically my answer :) You have to set src of image after setting onload handler otherwise onload event could be not called on cached image (browser behaviour)

Comment: @maximkou, I tried your solution, but the images don't load in the order they come in so it can move on before the every image is loaded.

Comment: @maximkou is there a way for me to mark this question as answered? I updated the original post to show my changed code in case future googlers want to see my solution.

Comment: @Braains, without selecting an answer? If yes, then I do not know.

Comment: @maximkou I figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jnt9f/

Setting onload handler before setting img src will make sure the onload event be fired even the image is cached

```
var $imgs = $(),i=0;
for (var img = 0; img < imageURLarray.length; img++) {
   $imgs = $imgs.add('<img/>');
}

var fctn = (function fctn(i){
    $imgs.eq(i).on('load',function(){
        //do some stuff
        //...
        fctn(++i);
    }).attr('src',imageURLarray[i]);    
})(0);
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain a little of what is happening in your example code? I'm not as familiar with JQuery as I should be.

Comment: This is to avoid any race condition. You will start loading next image only when previous as fully loaded. See jsfiddle in updated answer

Comment: After I try implementing the other answer I will try this. I'm a little more familiar with recursion than JQuery so I want to try that first.

Answer (score 0):

Actually...a lot of developers are pointing here to detect when images are done loading after a jQuery event..

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

If you can determine when the event triggers your images to load (for example, adding an Id or class onto the page right before your images begin to load), then you should be able to blend that in with this plug-in on github.

Good Luck!

Comment: Tried that, but I'm not just loading one image, I'm loading an image each time through the loop. All of this happens after the page loads.

Comment: The problem with preloading is that I'm dealing with a potentially large number of images.

Comment: whats triggering these "additional" images to load?

Comment: my script is loading an image each time through the loop with
    var currentimage = new Image();
    currentimage.src = imageURLarray[img];