# jQuery wait for image to load before looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my `js` and `jq` code :

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var $nItem = $('.Search_result_template').clone().removeClass("Search_result_template");
    src = Link_DB + data[i]._id + "/" + ReadConfigurationSettings_img_Upload_Name()+"0";
    $("<img/>")
        .on('load', function () {
            alert("image loaded correctly");
            alert("src: " + src);
            $nItem.find('.var_link_img').attr('href', src);
        })
        .on('error', function () {
            alert("error loading image"); var src = ReadConfigurationSettings_Link_Default_img();
            $nItem.find('.var_link_img').attr('href', src);
        })
        .attr("src", src);
    $nItem.find('.var_link_img').text('Image');
    $nItem.attr("id", "Search_result_template_" + i);
    //alert($nItem.html());
    $Search_Result.append($nItem);
}
```

The loop is iterated before testing if the image loaded successfully or there is an error. Thus, if I have many elements the src isn't correctly associated to each image link.

How can I wait for:

```
$("<img/>").on('load', function () {});
```

to be executed so i can get the good src for `$nItem.find('.var_link_img').attr('href', src);`

The result of this code shows the first link(`i==0`) as null and the second one(`i==1`) with the src of the precedent.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript waiting until an image is fully loaded before continuing script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919862/javascript-waiting-until-an-image-is-fully-loaded-before-continuing-script)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044852/preloading-images-in-html