# jQuery animations give choppy transitions when changing the src attribute of an image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, preload

I have been using `$().hide` and `$().show` to make a smooth transition between images in a slideshow-like fashion. For example, when the right arrow key is pressed, the current image being displayed will slide to the left and disappear, the image will change, and it will slide into view from the right. This is the code I use for such a transition:

```js
$('#mainImage').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 200);
$('#mainImage').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 700);
setTimeout(function() { changeImg(pageNumberNew); }, 200);
```

The `setTimeout()` function is purely to control when in the transition the image source will change. The `pageNumberNew` variable is the URL of the image to be changed to. Here is the `changeImg()` function:

```js
function changeImg(number) {
      document.getElementById('mainImage').setAttribute('src', "/largefiles/2021roadatlas/Images/" + number + ".jpeg");
      curPageNumber = number;
      setWidth();
}
```

However, on the first transition of images, it will become very choppy, because the images haven't been loaded yet. **I have tried various methods of preloading images**, such as

[Preloading images with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646036/preloading-images-with-javascript)

[Preloading images with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery)

[Waiting for image to load in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342132/waiting-for-image-to-load-in-javascript)

[JavaScript waiting until an image is fully loaded before continuing script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919862/javascript-waiting-until-an-image-is-fully-loaded-before-continuing-script)

But none of these have worked.

Once an image has been loaded for the first time, navigating back to that image will be smooth. I would like a solution where these images can be preloaded before the user starts interacting, possibly loading each image before the transitions take place - causing for a slight delay in starting the animation, but allowing it to be smooth.

You can see what I have so far in action [here](https://steepatticstairs.github.io/interactiveRA/index.html), if you type in `13` and use the right and left arrow keys. The animations might not be choppy if you use desktop, try that website on mobile to see the issue.

**TO BE CLEAR:** I want a way to **preload** images in JavaScript, but I **haven't been able** to use the normal methods of preloading images, as described above.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is loading so slow is the large image. You should make the image size of the original photo smaller. I can see that the original size is around 5000 x 6500 and you are scaling it down to around 1000 x 600. The original image is unnecessarily big which causes the slow load.